# Can't submit a commit to the master branch

Tags: git, gerrit

We have a stand alone gerrit  server, version 3.0.1.
We imported an existing git directory, by adding a symbolic link to the /git/ repository, pointing to the location of the git repository.

1. When I look at the UI at the repository-> branches tab, I can browse all the created branches - but not the master branch. The master is seen only as "HEAD" - master with a "EDIT" button, and no hash for it head. When looking at the git repository through git bash, it looks fine. (see image 1).
   [gerrit branch tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXcEq.jpg)
2. I added (I thinks..) all the required access rights to the repository - verify, code review , and submit. 
   [repository access rights image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTR7h.jpg).
   I can submit a commit to any of the new branches- but when a commit is sent to to master branch (push to HEAD:refs/for/master) - the submit button is missing. The verify and code review marks are set on +1, +2 - but the submit button is missing.

Why can't I see the master branch? Is it the reason I can't merge into it - or is it an access rights issue?

Comment: Have you grant permissions to "refs/*" too?

Comment: Adding repositories via symbolic links is not the way you should add them, as you have to do some work manually that way (reindex etc.). Have you tried creating a new repository in Gerrit the regular way and then pushing the existing one? E.g. as Administator (or as a user with at least Project Owner permissions) to push to that new repository from a local mirror (e.g. `git clone --mirror <current URL>`, `git add remote gerrit <URL>`, `git push --mirror gerrit [...]`?

Comment: Adding the "refs/*" solved the problem. Thanks!